How do you connect a vertex to a mirrored version of itself?
I've probably butchered the title, but I think its a simple answer I can't find.
Here's a picture of my issue, it seems easy to solve but I've been stumped for a couple minutes now.
Basically I want to fill in the void left with a simple straight edge, but I'm not sure how, anybody know?

The vertices generated by a modifier don't really exist in edit mode. (You edit only the original mesh, not modified)
So, you can't interact with the mirrored vertice.

Solution 1:

Turn on clipping in the mirror modifier
Keep the merge option on in the mirror modifier
Extrude the original vertice towards the mirror plane

The point will stop at the mirror limit (clipping option) and it will merge with the mirrored point (merge option)

Solution 2:
(not recommended unless you know you want to change objects in a non-mirrored way)

Leave edit mode
"Apply" the mirror modifier
Select both vertices and fill.

